# Is the Ioun Wyrd blind?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

I've heard that the Ioun Wyrd is blind, except for its blindsight, is this true? It seems much more powerful then the other familiars on most points so I'm wondering if there is any downside to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**

In fact, besides its blindsight (not blindsense), the [Ioun Wyrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/ioun-wyrd) is of the [construct type](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct) and all constructs have darkvision and low-light vision.  Nothing in its monster entry indicates exceptions to this general rule. It can't speak, however.

There is no additional fluff in the Familiar Folio except for mentions of Nex and Thuvia edited out for OGL reasons that might justify this belief.

To create one you need CL5 and spend 1500 gp plus an ioun stone in its creation, so it's more expensive than say the banana slug. The ability to fly and blindsense is cool, somewhat offset by its inability to speak tactically/scouting-wise. And +1 to the caster's natural armor is a good benefit. Its ability to store ioun stones is not (I've never said "boy it would be a good tactical idea to strap 50,000 gp worth of loot to my familiar").

Comment: Do you still need to pay if its your familiar and if so, where is this stated?

Comment: Someone has to because you don't get an ioun stone for free just by calling a familiar.  It's not "stated" but since there's construction rules it's common sense, and is the general assumption e.g. on the Paizo boards, cf. http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rxu3?Ioun-Wyrds-Stone-For-Starting-Characters and http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2szs1?Ioun-Wyrd-available-at-character-creation

Comment: Thanks for the links, The no speaking part is over-ruled by the level 5 ability speak with master, right?

Comment: @Simon Not entirely. The speak with master ability says, "If the master is 5th level or higher, a familiar and the master can communicate verbally as if they were using a common language. Other creatures do not understand the communication without magical help." So the ioun wyrd still can't *via* speak with master, for example, activate a command-word-triggered magic item nor tell the other PCs the wizard had fallen down a well (and it wouldn't be very good at communicating the latter in writing either!).